# Increment value is not coming order wise, when GROUP BY clause uses in select query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

SEQ_NO value is not coming order wise when I use Group by caluse or join a table. SEQ_NO should come order wise even I use ORDER BY clause for another column.

```
set @S = 0; 
SELECT (@S:=@S+1) AS SEQ_NO, abc, def 
from table 
group by abc 
order by abc
```

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Yes, the MySQL manual does say that using variables in the same script that define/alter them isn't a good idea. What nasty hack are you trying to achieve that's making you do this?

Comment: (My first recommendation would be that you upgrade to MySQL 8 and use ROW_NUMBER())

Comment: Everyone get over to the dupe and upvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46753800/2757035), which mentions that you can do this natively in MySQL now rather than hacking it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY numValue) AS SEQ_NO, abc, def
FROM table_name
GROUP BY abc
ORDER BY abc
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c840f49132b74a951131feccfea8067)

In case you are using MySQL earlier 8.0 you have to use a sub-query:

```
SELECT (@S:=@S+1) AS SEQ_NO, t.* 
FROM (
  SELECT abc, def
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY abc
  ORDER BY abc
) t, (SELECT @S:=0) sn
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1314e56d1eb2aa7791665ddc14886612)

You also `GROUP BY abc` but also using `def` column in result. The `def` column is a nonaggregated column in this case so the query isn't valid if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled.

Comment: @saveeshpm - which mysql version you are using?

Comment: 10.3.16 maria db